# Blazor WASM Hosted - Authorize on API Always returns UnAuthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, blazor, webassembly

I have a blazor wasm hosted solution that is setup using Role authentication. However, whenever I add an [Authorize] attribute to any of my API Controllers I get a 401 Unauthorized. I know the user has the proper role as the UI is showing and hiding features for that role.  Its like the roles are not being passed up to the API.  What am I missing?

Server - Starup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Register the Datacontext and Connection String
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            //Sets up the default Asp.net core Identity Screens - Use Identity Scaffolding to override defaults
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>( options =>
                    {
                        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                    })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

            //Associates the User to Context with Identity
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, DataContext>( options =>
                {
                    options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
                    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
                });

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove(JwtClaimTypes.Role);

            //Adds authentication handler
            services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();

            //Register Repositories for Dependency Injection
            services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext dataContext)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //AutoMigrates data
            dataContext.Database.Migrate();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSerilogIngestion();
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
```

Client - Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Serilog 
            var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("InstanceId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n"))
                .WriteTo.BrowserHttp(controlLevelSwitch: levelSwitch)
                .CreateLogger();

            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("XXX.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("XXX.ServerAPI"));

            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization()
                .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RolesClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

            var baseAddress = new Uri($"{builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress}api/"); 

            void RegisterTypedClient<TClient, TImplementation>(Uri apiBaseUrl)
                where TClient : class where TImplementation : class, TClient
            {
                builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(client =>
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = apiBaseUrl;
                });
            }

            RegisterTypedClient<ICountryService, CountryService>(baseAddress);


            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

RolesClaimPrincipalFactory.cs

```
public class RolesClaimsPrincipalFactory : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>
    {
        public RolesClaimsPrincipalFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor) : base(accessor)
        {
        }

        public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(
            RemoteUserAccount account,
            RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
                Claim[] roleClaims = identity.FindAll(identity.RoleClaimType).ToArray();

                if (roleClaims != null && roleClaims.Any())
                {
                    foreach (Claim existingClaim in roleClaims)
                    {
                        identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);
                    }

                    var rolesElem = account.AdditionalProperties[identity.RoleClaimType];

                    if (rolesElem is JsonElement roles)
                    {
                        if (roles.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
                        {
                            foreach (JsonElement role in roles.EnumerateArray())
                            {
                                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(options.RoleClaim, role.GetString()));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(options.RoleClaim, roles.GetString()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Told you your issue merits a new question , didn't I ;)

Comment: You did.  Any ideas as to why im receiving unauthorized from the API?

Comment: How are you calling your API from the client - using the `ICountryService`-client or the `XXX.ServerAPI`-named client?

Comment: The API is called from the ICountryService which uses DI for an HttpClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely having this issue since you are using `ICountryService` that has it's own http client which is not configured to include auth tokens in the outgoing requests -- no tokens, no access.

We can attach tokens by adding an `AuthorizationMessageHandler` to the client, just like your named client (`XXX.ServerAPI`) is configured.

Try changing your typed client helper method to this:

```cs
/* Client Program.cs */

void RegisterTypedClient<TClient, TImplementation>(Uri apiBaseUrl)
    where TClient : class where TImplementation : class, TClient
{
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(
            client => client.BaseAddress = apiBaseUrl)
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
}
```

You probably want to change the helper to also only include tokens to client's that actually require them (if you are using that helper for other clients as well)

[See the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios) for more info.

Comment: So that is a big step in the right direction and i will mark this as the answer.  One thing I am coming across is when the httpclient makes a call to the API with the Authorize attribute on it and its coming from a client that is not logged in (no access token) i get an exception of AccessTokenNotAvailableException instead of getting a 401 unauthorized

Comment: @JoeyD Nice. And yes - that is to be expected - you will have to catch that exception and forward the user to the login page in those cases. Please review the very first section of the docs link I posted as it talks about this (with written out code examples in the second code snippet of that page)

Comment: Thanks @Michel Jansson for all the info!